# WPBakery Visual Composer Wordpress plugin not loading custom post for logged in user

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, visual-composer

i created custom post "Blog" and i want to show all blogs in front using ajax. 
so i use "post masonry grid" and in that i add custom post(blog) term.
now its load all blog post for non logged in user and admin but not for other user roles..
 my Ajax call

```
action : vc_get_vc_grid_data
vc_action   :vc_get_vc_grid_data
tag :vc_masonry_grid
data[visible_pages] :5
data[page_id]   :1455
data[style] :all-masonry
data[action]    :vc_get_vc_grid_data
data[shortcode_id]:1469597061998-22b221b6-5511-6
data[tag]   :vc_masonry_grid
vc_post_id  :1455
_vcnonce    :651e0ea83a
```

when i check more in depth i found that it will generate same attributes.
i find out function process of Ajax call..

```
getGridDataForAjax() -> renderAjax() -> buildItems()
```

in buildItems function, there is query to get all post.

```
$settings = $this->filterQuerySettings( $this->buildQuery( $this->atts ) );
$post_data = query_posts( $settings );
```

$settings value is same for both case(where logged in or not) but for logged in user its always get 0 post.
i don't able to find out what's wrong because query attribute is some in both case.